# Error message does not displayed after validation with firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to validate if my username already exists in firestore database. If it already exists, it will show a message in the textbox. I have successfully checked the value in firestore, by looking at the printed value. But somehow, the message when the username exists, does not showing. Any idea why?

Check if username exists in firestore:

```
Future<bool> _isUsernameExists(String username) async {
  final QuerySnapshot result = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .where('username', isEqualTo: username)
      .limit(1)
      .getDocuments();
  final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
  return documents.length == 1;
}
```

Username textformfield:

```
    final _username = Container(
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: username),
        validator: (input) {
          if (input.isEmpty) {
            return msg_usermame_empty;
          } else {
            _isUsernameExists(input.toLowerCase().trim()).then((onValue) {
              if (onValue) {
                print('exists');
                return msg_username_exists;
              }else{
                print('not exists');
              }
            });
          }
        },
        onSaved: (input) => _stringUsername = input.toLowerCase().trim(),
      ),
    );

return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar(text: sign_up),
      body: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 20.0, 30.0, 0.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                _fullName,
                SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                _username,
                SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                _email,
                SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                _password,
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                _signUpButton,
                SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

_isUsernameExists is async fucntion and you are not using await.And returns are not in the right place.

```
 bool exist = await _isUsernameExists(input.toLowerCase().trim());
 if (exist) {
   print('exists');
   return msg_username_exists;
 }else{
   print('not exists');
   //return msg_username_not_exists;
 }
```